# Login register for android

Tags: android, passwords

I'm doing a registration for an android application. Initially, whenever the password and confirm password is not the same, the statement "Password & Confirm Password does not match" will be prompt and it works successfully. However, if the password & Confirm password matches with blanks, this statement should appear, "Do not leave any field empty", unfortunately it fails.

Do help me check for any error.

```
  btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String username, password, cpassword, fullname, nric, address, phone, email;
                username = tf3.getText().toString();
                password = tf4.getText().toString();
                cpassword = tf5.getText().toString();
                fullname = tf6.getText().toString();
                nric = tf7.getText().toString();
                address = tf8.getText().toString();
                phone = tf9.getText().toString();
                email = tf10.getText().toString();

                if(password != cpassword)
                {
                    tv1.setText("Password & Confirm Password does not match.");
                }
                else if(username.equals("") || password.equals("") || cpassword.equals("") || fullname.equals("") || nric.equals("") || address.equals("") || phone.equals("") || email.equals(""))
                {
                    tv1.setText("Do not leave any field empty.");
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        db.beginTransaction();
                        db.execSQL("insert into Members values('"+username+"','"+password+"','"+fullname+"','"+nric+"','"+address+"','"+phone+"','"+email+"');");
                        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                        db.endTransaction();    
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                        tv1.setText("Register Complete.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing it in wrong way, just compare your password & Confirm Password as follows,

```
if(!password.equals(cpassword))
```

In Java when you want to compare two String variables you need to use `equals()` method of String class.

```
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String username, password, cpassword, fullname, nric, address, phone, email;
            username = tf3.getText().toString();
            password = tf4.getText().toString();
            cpassword = tf5.getText().toString();
            fullname = tf6.getText().toString();
            nric = tf7.getText().toString();
            address = tf8.getText().toString();
            phone = tf9.getText().toString();
            email = tf10.getText().toString();

            if(!password.equals(cpassword))  // Change is here
            {
                tv1.setText("Password & Confirm Password does not match.");
            }
            else if(username.equals("") || password.equals("") || cpassword.equals("") || fullname.equals("") || nric.equals("") || address.equals("") || phone.equals("") || email.equals(""))
            {
                tv1.setText("Do not leave any field empty.");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    db.beginTransaction();
                    db.execSQL("insert into Members values('"+username+"','"+password+"','"+fullname+"','"+nric+"','"+address+"','"+phone+"','"+email+"');");
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    db.endTransaction();    
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
                    tv1.setText("Register Complete.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare password and confirm password field as follows.

```
if(!password.equals(cpassword)){

    tv1.setText("Password & Confirm Password does not match.");

}
```

hope it hepls.. always use **equals()** to compare two strings.